# Qual o significado de do erro 406?

Tags: http

> Not Acceptable
>
> An appropriate representation of the requested resource
>   /aa/bb/cc.php could not be found on
>   this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Recebendo este erro, o que remete?

Entendo que a página está negando acesso aos recursos, mas quais poderiam ser os motivos para isto correr?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É um problema de *content type*. Provavelmente a requisição ou resposta está usando um [*mime-type*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipo_de_m%C3%ADdia_da_Internet) que o servidor ou o cliente não pode manipular. Também pode ser um *charset* ou *encoding* inválido. Ainda pode ser uma língua inválida ou o tamanho do recurso. Provavelmente um dos dois lados está mal configurado. O mais provável é que esteja recebendo isto em algum cliente específico que não está mandando a requisição corretamente.

Como não há detalhes, só dá para responder genericamente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: estava a enviar a requisição através do seguinte formato: `http://www.dominio.com.br/subdominio/arquivo.php`, e dava o erro 406, alterei para `http://www.subdominio.dominio.com.br/arquivo.php` e funcionou, existe alguma explicação? Posso acessar normalmente o arquivo da primeira maneira, mas ao tentar enviar uma requisição com cURL da primeira maneira não parece funcionar, apenas no formato anterior( e de fato, é um subdominio que está hospedado o arquivo).

Comment: Só com estas informações é difícil explicar. Mas é comum dar esse tipo de erro usado um cliente que não seja um navegador. O programador sempre esquece de fazer alguma coisa.

Comment: Para acrescentar afim de ajudar futuras consultas, eu adicionei a seguinte linha e me ajudou a resolver também, `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);`

Comment: Faz sentido....

Answer (score 0):

Tive o mesmo problema mas com o erro HTTP 406 em uma requisição com cURL na linguagem PHP, consegui solucionar acrescentando o `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```